# MySQL and virtual environment

Tags: python, mysql, django, virtualenv, mysql-python

I have MySQL installed on Mac, but when I use virtual environment to create a Django project , it seems like it cannot find the MySQLdb, is it because I dont have MySQL and MySQLdb inside the created virtual environment?

```
Should I have a seperated MySQL and MySQLbd for each virtualenv? 
What about MySQLworkbench, should i do the same, if I want to use it?
```

Comment: `pip install MySQL-python` ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your MySQL deamon is in the PATH, there should not be any trouble. (the virtualenv just add a PATH entry to influence binary resolution but does not remove any PATH entry)

Try to check what a gives you out :

```
which MySQLdb
```

if there is no output then there is a MySQL installation problem.

BTW how did you install MySQL : did you use homebrew (or another package manager) or did you use a dmg image ?

Comment: where is no output. I install it with homebrew. how could i put MySQL daemon in the PATH?